# Show that $e^{xy}+y=x-1$ is an implicit solution to the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{e^{-xy}-y}{e^{-xy}+x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-differentiation

I began by using implicit differentiation on $e^{xy}+y=x-1$.

From that I  got:

$$\left(y+x\frac{dy}{dx}\right)e^{xy}+\frac{dy}{dx}=1$$

Then using algebra I got to the point where I had this equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1-ye^{xy}}{xe^{xy}+1}$$

I'm not sure if I messed up somewhere along the road, or if my final equation is actually the equivalent to $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{e^{-xy}-y}{e^{-xy}+x}$ but I would like help knowing either where I went wrong or how to convert my equation to the final answer.

Comment: You did the hard part. Multiply numerator and denominator by $e^{-xy}$!

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you! I had a feeling I was close...

Comment: Your answer is better I see no interest to wite it differently Drew

Comment: @Isham I agree! I think it looks better without the negative exponents, but I have to be victim to the whims of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $$e^{xy}y+e^{xy}y'x+y'=1$$so we get
$$y'(e^{xy}x+1)=1-ye^{x}$$
$$y'=\frac{1-ye^{xy}}{1+x^{xy}}$$
multiplying numerator and denominator by $$e^{-xy}$$
we get
$$y'=\frac{e^{-xy}-y}{e^{-xy}+x}$$
this is what we want to prove

Comment: Thank you very much! I had a feeling I was going in the right direction, I just couldn't picture how to make my last equation look like the one they were looking for.

Comment: ok have a nice evening, just another problem was solved!